# RHEL 6.0 upgrading kernel from 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 to 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel

[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ivh kernel-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies: 
    **bfa-firmware < 3.0.3.1 conflicts with kernel-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64** 
 
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -qa |grep bfa 
bfa-firmware-3.0.0.0-1.el6.noarch
 

Please kindly tell me whats the actual error

Comment: You made a mistake by manually downloading the RPM and installing it with the `rpm` command. You should use `yum` to install packages instead.

Answer (score 1):

The later kernel requires a later version of the bfa-firmware package.

If you used yum to install the new kernel, yum would download the latest bfa-firmware package as well, and both packages (bfa-firmware and kernel) would be installed.

To upgrade to this kernel with rpm, you need to download bfa-firmware-3.0.3.1 or later and install that using rpm, then you'll be able install the later kernel package.